# datagridview combobox column in c#.net windows forms

Tags: c#-4.0

hi friends iam creating datagridview combobox column in windows forms from load. but at run time iam not getting the values in comboboxcolumn of datagridview. iam using bellow code

```
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn clnStatus = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        clnStatus.DataPropertyName = "Status";
        clnStatus.Name = "Absent - Leave - Present";
        clnStatus.DataSource = new string[] { "Absent", "Leave", "Present" };
        DgvTeacherAttendance.Columns.Add(clnStatus);
```

here combobox column will display empty values before i select anyone of the dropdown list.
why iam getting these error please can anyone help me.